# Removing last elements of a list if they match a pattern

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

Given a list of numeric Strings `[1,3,5,0,2,0,0,0]`. Is there a way to remove the last 0, to obtain `[1,3,5,0,2]`, if possible using streams.

Comment: you mean duplicate number?

Comment: I just want to remove the three last 0 without removing the 0 who are not at the end of the list.

Comment: This is just an example, it could be different numbers of 0 at the end.

Comment: ...and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why you should use streams in this case. The following snippet is short and simple. I would recommend you this way.

```
    String[] stringarray = { "1", "3", "5", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0" };

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(stringarray));

    while (strings.get(strings.size() - 1).equals("0")) {
        strings.remove(strings.size() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: `int count = 2;
        while (strings.get(strings.size() - 1).equals("0") && count>=0 ) {
            count--;
            strings.remove(strings.size() - 1);
        }` because wont work for `{ "1", "3", "5", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0","0" }`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on java9 at least:

```
List<String> inputList = ...
Predicate<String> predicate = ...

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(inputList);
Colledtions.reverse(result);
result = result.stream
    .dropWhile(predicate)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, interessting but I run Java8 only and can't use dropWhile. Anyway you're right, reverse mechanism could be usefull here.

Comment: Or you could even create a Deque from input and pop() while your strings match

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution

```
String[] stringarray = { "1", "3", "5", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0" };
int count = 0;

             for(int i = stringarray.length; i > 0; i--) {
                 if("0".equals(stringarray[i-1])) {
                     count ++;
                 } else {
                     break;
                 }
             }

 String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(stringarray, stringarray.length - count);
```